# Rube.exe: No such file or directory in Babun

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cygwin

I'm trying to install rubygems in Babun so I can install sass and compass but keep getting error:

```
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.1.0\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- /cygdrive/c/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/gem (LoadError)
```

I have ruby in my env Path, rebooted system, but still getting error:

***Test ***

{ ~ } » which ruby

```
/cygdrive/c/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby
```

{ ~ } » ruby -v

```
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [i386-mingw32]
```

When I tried installing gem in Windows cmd, everything worked OK. It's just not working in Babun.

Answer (score 5):

The similar problem was described here: https://github.com/babun/babun/issues/359

According to the above situation type in gem.bat instead of gem.

You could add the alias to make your life easier (on the babun console):

```
alias gem=gem.bat
```

I had that kind of situation with Jekyll (http://jekyllrb.com/) and it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much!