# Not able to execute Rails version command from Babun shell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cygwin

I have installed Rails 4.2 on my Windows machine along with Babun (a cygwin superset). However, after installation it is not able to recognize the rails version when i execute rails -v command. However, both the commands just work fine on Windows command prompt.

**Babun Shell:**

```
{ ~ }  » ruby -v                                                                                                                                                                       
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [i386-mingw32]
{ ~ }  » rails -v                                                                                                                                                                        
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.1.0\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- /cygdrive/c/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/rails (LoadError)
```

**Windows Command Prompt:**

```
C:\Users>ruby -v
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [i386-mingw32]
C:\Users>rails -v
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Rails 4.2.2
```

**Rails Installation directory structure:**

```
C:/RailsInstaller
    DevKit
    Ruby2.1.0
        bin
    scripts
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute following command from any directory:

```
alias rails=rails.bat
```

Found a clue from this post: [Rube.exe: No such file or directory in Babun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32389877/rube-exe-no-such-file-or-directory-in-babun)